# Dynamically add event handler to an href which is also dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button and when this button is clicked I need to generate a link dynamically and add a handler to it which shows a twitter bootstrap modal. I tried this:

```
$(function() {

  function showModal() {
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
  }

  $(document).on("click", "#my_btn", function() {
    //generating a link a adding a handler to it which is "showModal()"
    //.....
    $("#my_href").html("Some text123 <a href='#' onclick='showModal();'>test123</a>.");
    //.....
  })
});
```

But when I clink a this link the error is being thrown saying

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: showModal is not defined
```

I can, of course, move `showModal()`  out of `$(function() {...})`. But I was wondering, is there a better way to do it? And in general, is this a good way to achieve what I want?

UPDATE:
Even after moving `showModal()`  out of `$(function() {...})` it doesn't work, it redirects me to the same page but doesn't show pop up.

Comment: What is my_href, a container I hope and not a link itself

Comment: You're being redirect because the default behaviour of the `a` element is to redirects the user to the url defined in its `href` attribute. To prevent this from occurring, use the `event` parameter passed to the event handler: `function showModal(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use inline Javascript. You've posted a perfect example of how you *should* be doing this right in your question: Use `.on` on the containing element.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#my_btn", function() {
    $("#my_href").html("Some text123 <a href='#'>test123</a>.");
 });

 $('#my_href').on('click', 'a', showModal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery delegated event handlers to add the click handler

```
$(function () {

    function showModal() {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    }

    $(document).on("click", "#my_btn", function () {
        //generating a link a adding a handler to it which is "showModal()"
        //.....
        $("#my_href").html("Some text123 <a href='#' class='showmodal'>test123</a>.");
        //.....
    });

    $("#my_href").on('click', '.showmodal', showModal)
});
```

In your case you have a inlined event handler which is calling `showModal`, this expects a method named `showModal` in the global scope but you have added the method `showModal` as a closure method in the dom ready handler.

Comment: why is `$("#my_href").on('click', '.showmodal', showModal)` located out of `$(document).on("click", "#my_btn",....`?

Comment: for some reason your code doesn't work, it still redirect me to the same page even though I've added e.preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   function showModal() {
     alert("Modal");
   }
    $('<a/>',{
        href: '#',
        text: "Click Me",
        click: function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          showModal();
        }
    }).appendTo('#my_href');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UAa7h/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you should attach your event to the body or document not to the button

```
 $("body").on( "click","button[id$=my_btn]",  function(){

        alert( "hi" );
    })
```